# SqlFunctions.StringConvert() is not working ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am migrating the application to the .net core.  but SqlFunctions.StringConvert() is not working in.netcore. 
I am using the following code:

```
using (var entity = new AppEntity())
            {
            var    physianAggregationList = (from physianAggregaton in entity.tbl_Physician_Aggregation_Year

                                          where (
                                                 (physianAggregaton.CMS_Submission_Year == cmsyear)
                                                 && (physianAggregaton.Physician_NPI == npi || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(npi)))
                                                 && physianAggregaton.Is_90Days == is_90Days && physianAggregaton.Exam_TIN == Tin                                                  
                                                 )
                                          select new Tindata
                                          {


                                              Performance_Rate = entity.tbl_Lookup_Measure.Where(i => i.Measure_num.ToLower() == physianAggregaton.Measure_Num.ToLower()
                                                                                                  && i.CMSYear == physianAggregaton.CMS_Submission_Year)
                                                                                                  .Select(x => x.Perf_Rate_Per_1000).FirstOrDefault() == boolValue
                                                                                                  ? (physianAggregaton.Performance_rate == null ? "NULL" : SqlFunctions.StringConvert(physianAggregaton.Performance_rate, 100, 2))
                                                                                                  : (physianAggregaton.Performance_rate == null ? "NULL" : SqlFunctions.StringConvert(physianAggregaton.Performance_rate, 100, 2) + "%"),


                                              Reporting_Rate = physianAggregaton.Reporting_Rate == null ? "NULL" : SqlFunctions.StringConvert(

                                              //}).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x.displayorder).ToList();
                                          }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ToList();
                ///logger.LogInfo("PhysianAggregation Count in getPhysianAggregationData():[" + physianAggregationList.Count()+"]");
            }
```

Comment: so.. what exactly error message you get?

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'SqlFunctions' does not exist in the current context

Comment: `DbFunctions` and `SqlFunctions` are from EF6. You shouldn't be mixing EF6 and EF Core libraries. Other than that, currently there is no EF Core equivalent of `StringConvert`.

Comment: can you help me, how can write the above query

Comment: What EF Core version are you using?

Comment: I am using the ef-core version 3.0.1

Answer (score 6):

`SqlFunctions` is EF6 specific class and cannot be used in EF Core. EF Core custom functions are available as extension methods of `EF.Functions`.

Unfortunately currently EF Core does not provide equivalent of `StringConvert`. But it can be added relatively easy by using the EF Core [Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping) and mapping to `STR` method similar to what EF6 was doing.

For instance, add the following class (with the necessary `using`s):

```
public static class SqlFunctions
{
    public static string ToString(this decimal? value, int? length, int? decimalArg) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public static string ToString(this double? value, int? length, int? decimalArg) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public static ModelBuilder AddSqlFunctions(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder) => modelBuilder
        .MapToSTR(() => ToString(default(decimal?), null, null))
        .MapToSTR(() => ToString(default(double?), null, null));
    static ModelBuilder MapToSTR(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Expression<Func<string>> method)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(method).HasTranslation(args =>
            new SqlFunctionExpression(null, null, "STR", false, args, true, typeof(string), null));
        return modelBuilder;
    }
}
```

then the following inside your `OnModelCreating` override:

```
if (Database.IsSqlServer()) modelBuilder.AddSqlFunctions();
```

then inside the query, replace

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert(physianAggregaton.Performance_rate, 100, 2)
```

with

```
physianAggregaton.Performance_rate.ToString(100, 2)
```

Comment: I will try ,thanls

Comment: Hi Ivan-Stoev, physianAggregaton.Performance_rate.ToString(100, 2). Here ToString() method does n't contain any parameters. How can round up decimal/double values ?

Comment: `ToString` method with parameters is the one from the above **custom** `SqlFunctions` class. You need to add that class to the project containing the `DbContext`, register it in model creating as explained, and them make sure it is visible to the calling code, e.g. `using Namespace_containing_StringFunctions_class;`

Comment: if (Database.IsSqlServer()) modelBuilder.AddSqlFunctions();  this code , I have added in the OnModelCreating(). but it is not visible in the calling code. How know to ToString() method round up the decimal values ?

Comment: It's an extension method. You must make the class visible to the calling code. Just add the `SqlFunctions` class in the same project and namespace where your `DbContext` derived class (`AppEntity`) is currently.

Comment: public static string ToString(this decimal? value, int? length, int? decimalArg) => throw new NotSupportedException(); is manually added. There is no extesion method

Comment: The keyword `this` before `decimal? value` and `double? value` is what makes them extension methods. If you like, you can use them as regular static method, e.g. `StringFunctions.ToString(physianAggregaton.Performance_rate, 100, 2)`. I just find extension syntax `physianAggregaton.Performance_rate.ToString(100, 2)` more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
_dbContext.Some
    .Where(x => x.Id.ToString().Contains("123"));
```

Comment: As of the EF Core 5.x, this code translates to the following string for SQL WHERE:
`(("123" LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX("123", CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [r0].[Id])) > 0))` 
For me it looks like efficient server-side. Kudos for the answer.